# facebook Graph API ordering images using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey all I have the following Graph API call

```
me?fields=cover,id,name,photos.limit(10){likes{name,id},images,created_time.order(chronological),picture}&type=uploaded
```

Using **created_time.order(chronological)** should show my images from newest to oldest but it seems to just be showing older to oldest?

```
"created_time": "2015-10-13T23:05:52+0000",
...
"created_time": "2015-07-13T23:43:16+0000",
...
"created_time": "2015-06-09T23:30:16+0000",
...
"created_time": "2015-03-26T21:04:30+0000",
etc....etc...
```

When I do my graph call this way:

```
me/photos?fields=created_time.order(chronological),likes{name,id},images&limit=15&type=uploaded
```

it DOES show my images in the correct order:

```
"created_time": "2018-03-26T22:11:53+0000",
...
"created_time": "2017-12-08T18:57:53+0000",
...
"created_time": "2017-06-05T21:14:28+0000",
...
"created_time": "2017-05-04T21:07:40+0000",
etc..etc..
```

But that call is missing the **cover** field that I also need that the first one has.

Is there a way to do this that has both **cover** and the ability to order the images by chronological?